# Unable to Initialize Vulkan on Juno

Tags: release-juno, nvidia

I have a Lenovo y50-70 with a GTX 860M Nvidia card.

I am using a fresh install of Elementary OS 5.0 and upgraded to the Nvidia 430 using the Additional Drivers GUI.

I have also installed libvulkan1 and vulkan-utils

When I try to check Vulkan via `$ vulkaninfo | less`

I get the following output:

```
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
/build/vulkan-tools-Igvqg5/vulkan-tools-1.1.114.0+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.c:5884: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.114
```

I am very new to linux, so obviously I am missing something. How do I get Vulkan working in this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS solved my problem